# How to calculate NTP

Tags: ntp

I'm relatively new to this scene and I haven't got a clue how to figure out the output of this. I hope someone can assist as I really want to learn how.

`date -u +%F | sha1sum | head -c8;  echo`

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Figure out the output"? Do you perhaps want to know what this command does, the purpose, etc. Please [edit] your question to inclue some more context; where you found this and what exactly your question is about it. I'll be happy to provide an answer once the question is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Using `date` and `sha1sum`

```
date -u +%F | sha1sum | head -c8;  echo
```

- `date -u +%F`

  prints the system date and time

  E.G. `2015-04-24`

  - `-u`- UTC instead of CEST
  - `+%F` - full date; same as %Y-%m-%d
- `sha1sum`

  compute SHA1 message digest

  E.G. `e1a9d1a9de6f784ae30c6c1d5be9fc897ea5e4ec  -`
- `head -c8`

  output the first part of files

  E.G. `e1a9d1a9%`

  - `-c8` - print the first 8K bytes
- `echo`

  display a line of text

  E.G. `e1a9d1a9`